# Tactic for existential hypothesis

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Say we have a proposition `P1 n`, and there `exists n` for which it holds. Furthermore we have a proposition `P2`, where `P1 n` implies `P2` for any `n`. How do we prove `P2`?

```
Parameter P1 : nat -> Prop.
Axiom some_p1 : exists n, P1 n.

Parameter P2 : Prop.
Axiom p1_implies_p2 : forall n, P1 n -> P2.

Theorem p2 : P2.
```

I tried

```
Proof.
  eapply p1_implies_p2.
```

which gives me the goal `P1 ?n`, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may eliminate `some_p1`to get a witness `n`and a hypothesis `Hn`.

```
Theorem p2 : P2.
  case some_p1 ; intros n Hn.  apply (p1_implies_p2 _ Hn).
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! The documentation also suggests that instead of [case](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacn.case) and intros, one might use [destruct](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacn.destruct).

Comment: Yes, but, in general, prefer variants of `destruct` with explicit naming of new variables/hypotheses, like `destruct some_p1 as [n Hn]` and not plain `destruct some_p1` (for readability/maintenance's sake).

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, if you use the SSReflect proof language, Pierre's proof idea would look like this:

```
Theorem p2 : P2.
Proof. move: some_p1 => [n p1n]. exact: (p1_implies_p2 p1n). Qed.
```

Note that providing the second argument `p1n` to `p1_implies_p2` is enough, since the omitted first one, `n`, can be inferred by Coq.